# Apex Test Class failing on second asserEquals statement

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex, apex-code

Test Class failing on asserEqual:

I am trying to use this Test Class to test a isBefore && isInsert or IsUpdate Trigger but the test is failing on second assertEquals statement (end of the code, trying to compare return of SOQL Query:

I don't know why this is taking because I am doing a few simple inserts to test my Trigger.

Complete code:

````
@isTest
private class Test_Triggers{
    static testMethod void Test_Triggers() {

        Account acc = new Account();
            acc.Name = 'sacasac';
        insert acc;

        Account contateste0 = new Account();
            contateste0.Name = 'GRANITOS E MARMORES MACHADO LTDA EPP';
            contateste0.Phone = '(27)3727-2929';
        insert contateste0;
        
        Contact contatoTeste = new Contact();
            contatoTeste.FirstName = 'TITANIUM';
            contatoTeste.LastName = 'TITANIUM';
            contatoTeste.Phone = '3329-4053';
            contatoTeste.MobilePhone = '27999970208';
            contatoTeste.Email = 'gmmcontabil@gmail.com';
            contatoTeste.AccountId = contateste0.Id;
        insert contatoTeste;
        
        Case novoCaso = new Case();
            novoCaso.Subject = 'assunto';
            novoCaso.Description = 'obs';
            novoCaso.AccountId = contateste0.Id;
            novoCaso.ContactId = contatoTeste.Id;
            novoCaso.Origin = 'Portal';
        insert novoCaso;

        Opportunity novaOpp = new Opportunity();
            novaOpp.AccountId = contateste0.Id;
            novaOpp.Amount = 4200;
            novaOpp.Name = '4200';
            novaOpp.StageName = 'Pré_Oportunidade';
            novaOpp.CloseDate = Date.today();
        insert novaOpp;

        Id idMeta = Schema.SObjectType.Meta__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('CORE').getRecordTypeId();
        Id idMeta2 = Schema.SObjectType.Meta__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('NOVO').getRecordTypeId();
        
        Meta__c meta01 = new Meta__c();
            meta01.Data__c = Date.today();
            meta01.Id_Usuario__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
            meta01.Id_Conta__c = contateste0.Id;
            meta01.RecordTypeId = idMeta;
            meta01.Valor__c = 53161;
        insert meta01;
        
        System.assertEquals(53161, meta01.Valor__c);
        
        Ordem_de_venda__c ordem = new Ordem_de_venda__c();
            ordem.Oportunidade__c = novaOpp.Id;
            ordem.Conta_Principal__c = acc.Id;
            ordem.Pagador__c = acc.Id;
            ordem.Data_de_vencimento__c = System.today().addDays(2);
            ordem.Id_Meta__c = meta01.Id;
            ordem.Tipo__c = 'Serviço';
            insert ordem;
               
 List<AggregateResult> aggregateOrdensVenda = [SELECT Id_Meta__c, sum(Valor_faturado__c) total, sum(VlrFor__c) forecast FROM Ordem_de_venda__c WHERE Id_Meta__c =:meta01.Id GROUP BY Id_Meta__c];

//This is failing because SOQL s returning nothing
        system.assertEquals(1,aggregateOrdensVenda.size());
}
}```
````

Comment: Weird. Does it return anything with basic `SELECT Id_Meta__c FROM Ordem_de_venda__c`? Are you sure the insert run, you didn't cut / anonymise any code? Look in the debug log for "DML _BEGIN". Does your trigger have something that could be changing the lookups, making your WHERE not valid anymore? Is this a "normal" test or do you use System.runAs? (I had situations where runAs end user + some assignment rules were "stealing" my data, I created say a Case but then it got assigned to Queue I couldn't see)

Comment: For sure, Ordem_de_Venda__c is inserting but when I try to retrieve all data from that record that I've just inserted the only field that I cannot get value is Id_Meta__c and I don't know why. This is a simple lookup field.

Comment: Check security. Does your profile / permission sets have field level security right to the lookup field and at least "Read" on the object it looks up to? When you insert the 1st object manually with these values - do you retain ownership or does it move to another user/queue? What's the org wide sharing default and sharing rules (if any)? The connection between them is lookup or M-D?

Comment: In a pinch you could say screw it, you know the only row returned will be the one just inserted (you don't have SeeAllData), even if 1 field comes blank... You don't *really* need that WHERE. But it's weird, would be nice to get to the bottom of this, could bite you in something more serious than unit test